# Differing ways to make executeQueryAsync calls - Function.createDelegate (is old IE8 code)

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, client-object-model, delegate

I want some understanding on two programming patterns I've seen and when to employ them. 
The question is about callbacks and delegate.

In the first code there are two distinct functions, success and fail, something I've always used, but the second code is different.

```
 function loadWebs() {

       var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

       this.webs = clientContext.get_web().get_webs();

       clientContext.load(this.webs);

       clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onWebsLoaded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

       alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());

    }

    function onWebsLoaded(sender, args) {

       for (var i = 0; i < this.webs.get_count(); i++) {

       alert(this.webs.itemAt(i).get_title());

       }    
    }
```

and the second code doesn't appear to use callbacks for the success, instead the success is wrapped in the parent function.

```
  myCtx.load(webs, "Include(Id, Lists)");

    myCtx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        // push new SP.ListItemCollections into an array and tell the ctx to fetch them
        for (var i = 0; i < webs.get_data().length; i++) {
            var web = webs.get_data()[i], itms;  
     if (checkForProjectsList(web)) {
                itms = webs.get_data()[i].get_lists()
                           .getByTitle("Projects").getItems(query);
                queryItemCollections.push(itms);
                myCtx.load(itms);
            }



        }


    myCtx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            queryItemCollections.forEach(function (item) {
                // do work with individual list items here
                console.log(item.getItemAtIndex(0).get_item("Title"));
            });
        }, genericFailHandler);
    }, genericFailHandler);


function genericFailHandler(sender, args) {
        console.log(args.get_message());
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn168907.aspx

states:

**SP.ClientContext.executeQueryAsync( succeededCallback , failedCallback )**

So in both your examples you are *referencing* a function (callback) as parameter.
The only difference being the *declaration* of the function.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions

With

```
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    function () {
        queryItemCollections.forEach(function (item) {
            console.log(item.getItemAtIndex(0).get_item("Title"));
        });
    }
  , genericFailHandler
);
```

you create a (anonymous) Success function callback (expression) which can **not** be (re)used by any other code.

While with:

```
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
  Function.createDelegate(this, this.onWebsLoaded),
  Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
);
```

you have declared seperate functions, so you could use that function (declaration) for other calls as well.

**Function.createDelegate**

Is (old, never a official standard) JavaScript code to bind the outer function *this* context to your function, it is supported in all browsers.
`.bind(this)` is standard ES5 JavaScript code
IE9 was the first IE version to support this `.bind()` notation. You need a Polyfill to support older IE browsers

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

So

```
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
  this.onWebsLoaded.bind(this),
  this.onQueryFailed.bind(this)
);
```

is a more modern notation

**But** in your examples above you do **nothing** with the *this* context inside the Fail function.

So you might as well write:

```
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
  this.onWebsLoaded.bind(this),
  this.onQueryFailed
);
```

And since your first example declares those functions as Global functions, you can write:

```
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
  onWebsLoaded.bind(this),
  onQueryFailed
);
```

#### Learning *this*

- http://www.sitepoint.com/inner-workings-javascripts-this-keyword/

Is a cool blog which also lets you play with *this* in JSBins

---

### Great explanation (including modern Arrow Functions):

### http://2ality.com/2017/12/alternate-this.html

---

J1 J5 JSOM JX iBind

Comment: In the second example there are two calls to  myCtx.executeQueryAsync. The first appears to get Projects lists and the second one gets every Title of the 1st Item in the Project list. The 1st call builds  myCtx.load(itms) and this gets executed in the second call. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes there are nested callbacks,That code is much better to read when restuctured to use declared functions.

Comment: So the use of `bind` won't work on IE 8? What about SP sites where the site defaults to IE8 compatibility mode on IE 11?

Comment: You can test with ``Function.call.bind({});`` in the F12 console