# Exception Handling Mechanisms in JSOM in SharePoint 2013 On-Premises

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jsom

Can anyone please provide how to handle the exceptions in JSOM in SharePoint 2013.
Currently I am developing a SharePoint 2013 On-Premises portal having JSOM as the approach for coding and while coding I need to put several functions and have to handle exceptions.

Is there any exception handling mechanisms available in JSOM or javascript ?
any free frameworks can I use ?

Comment: What do you want to catch what standard try-catch can't do?

Comment: Would like to know  what if an exception occurs in my CRUD operations in  UI against SPList & SPDocument Libraries. Will it log the  exception in LOGS folder's log files automatically? Similar to the implementation of  SPDiagnosticsServiceBase class available in SSOM.

Comment: (*I haven't done serious back-end in 10 years..so might be wrong here*) I wouldn't think exceptions are logged server-side because JSOM is Front-End technology calling an endpoint. If exceptions where logged server-side, us Front-End developers would have no way of accessing the info.

Comment: so do I really care about exceptions happening  in JSOM against y current env. which is SharePoint on-premises ? i will simply use try catch finally and and push that into console.log() whenever there is an error.

Comment: Before you deep dive into JSOM, check out Microsofts work which they use in modern developments: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core

Comment: but have a doubt, does this applies to SP 2013 on-premises? i think MS has created the  pnp-js-core by keeping O 365 in mind. i would be happy if i can reuse the APIs available in pnp-js-core in On-Premises.

Comment: They are the same REST endpoints.

Answer (score 3):

Everything in JSOM is client side. So the exceptions you get are not stored server side. 
You can use the on fail method as below to store & check exceptions in the console itself. Check below code snippet :

```
function getItems(camlQuery){

     var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
     var web = context.get_web();
     var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Test');
     var items = list.getItems(camlQuery, 'AllItems');

     context.load(items);
     context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onSuccess),   
     Function.createDelegate(this, onFailure));  

}

function onSuccess(sender, args) {
   //...success
   //execute your code
}

function onFailure(sender, args) {
    console.log('Request Failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());    
}
```

This will give you the error message as well as the stack trace in the console. 
To check the message, press F12 (opens developer tools) and click on console tab.

`onFailure` method can be used across different functions.

Comment: function onSuccess(sender, args) { } can i use try {}  catch () {} finally {} here ?

Comment: No, they are not Promises, you have to wrap it in a Promise yourself. And Function.createDelegate is oldskool below IE9 code, [use .bind](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164912/query-multiple-lists-using-javascript-csom/164923#164923)

Answer (score 1):

Try catch does not work that well with async, you could use [SP.ExceptionHandlingScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff411960(v=office.14).aspx) when you work against SharePoint data.

Simple example creating ClientContext against a none existing site:

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext("https://i-dont-exists");
ctx.load(ctx.get_web(), "Title");

var exceptionScope = new SP.ExceptionHandlingScope(ctx);  
var startScope = exceptionScope.startScope();  

var tryScope = exceptionScope.startTry();
       var web = ctx.get_web();
tryScope.dispose();  

var catchScope = exceptionScope.startCatch();  

    // DO stuff in catch
    ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current()
    ctx.load(ctx.get_web(), "Title");

catchScope.dispose();  

var finallyScope = exceptionScope.startFinally();  
    // DO Stuff in finally                          

finallyScope.dispose();  

startScope.dispose();  

ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() { 
    console.log(ctx.get_web().get_title());
}, function(s, args) { 
    console.log('Err: ' + args.get_message()); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
try {
    ...
}
catch (Exception) {
    //Get error code and act
}
finally {
    ...
}
```

Good article [here](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.in/2010/08/sharepoint-2010-exception-handling.html)

Comment: That good article does not mention ``throw() ``: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw

Comment: And is using CSOM, not JSOM.