# Error updating List Items

Tags: list, javascript, list-view, caml

**I have found this code to perform batch update**

```
function updateListItems() {

    var itemArray = [];
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('TestList');


    for(var i = 1; i<= 5; i++){

        var oListItem = oList.getItemById(i);  
        oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My Updated Item!' + i);  
        oListItem.update();
        itemArray[i] = oListItem;
        clientContext.load(itemArray[i]);
    }

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    alert('Items Updated');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
updateListItems();
```

**But I am getting the following error :**

> The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been
>   requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be
>   explicitly requested.

I need to update a various item in the list without iterating it.

Please Help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should you check this code

Create a new function and rename it as bulkupdate

```
Function BulkUpdate()
{

for(var i = 1; i<= 5; i++){ 
updateListItem(int i);
}

}
}


    var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';

    function updateListItem(int i) {

        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');


 this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(i);

        oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My Updated Title');

        oListItem.update();

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }

    function onQuerySucceeded() {

        alert('Item updated!');
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks buddy i found the solution.....but my new problem is i have to compare the item column with the new value......and i am getting this  error not while set_item method but while get_item method....help plss...if u want i can share the code in next question

Comment: and do not worry brother with that much of help...i will definetely vote your answer and mark correct

Comment: Hey buddy posted new....please help

Comment: Should you update your question with the new request please ? don't worry I am here to do my best and help you

Comment: already done bro..

Comment: Great news , good luck

Comment: Note: ``Function.createDelegate()`` is oldskool IE code: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164893/differing-ways-to-make-executequeryasync-calls-function-createdelegate/164898#164898