# Sequential dropdown lists

Tags: javascript, custom-list, dropdown

I am trying to make a simple double drop down list. I have the basic structure down I believe, but I am stuck on making the javascript work correctly.

I want the double drop downs to look as such:
[image]

The first dropdown allows you to select a department (i.e. accounting, HR, etc.). The second dropdown lets you choose a task inside of that department.

I currently have the links stored in a list like such:
[image]

My thought process was to make a column for departments, and then each of those departments should have their own column. That way, when the department is selected, I can use the text in that field to pull data from the correct department's column. I believe I have a good start, but I am looking for either a quicker way to do this, or a fix to my javascript.

Currently I am stuck on an error, and I understand the reasoning but not how to fix it. For reference, my code is below:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");

        function retrieveListItems() {
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); //create client context at this site collection.
            var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('LinkList'); //create list object by the title of the, projectParameters is the list to look through
            var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery(); //create CAMLquery to pull in list items.
            camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>'); //define the query, here we pull in the records where the project is active 
            this.collListitem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);//get the items from the list object based on the query defined above.

            clientContext.load(collListitem, 'Include(LinkTitle, Active, Acc, HR, Technology)');//telling the object model to prepare to execute the following object by loading it into the client context.

            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));  
        }
        function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
            var LinkTitle = '';
            var active = '';
            var accountingLink = '';
            var accountingTask = '';
            var hrLink = '';
            var hrTask = '';
            var technologyLink = '';
            var technologyTask = '';

            var listItemEnumerator = collListitem.getEnumerator();

            while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                LinkTitle += oListItem.get_item("LinkTitle") + ' ';
                active += oListItem.get_item("Active") + ' ';
                accountingLink += oListItem.get_item("Acc").get_url() + ' ';
                accountingTask += oListItem.get_item("Acc").get_description() + ' ';
                hrLink += oListItem.get_item("HR").get_url() + ' ';
                hrTask += oListItem.get_item("HR").get_description() + ' ';
                technologyLink += oListItem.get_item("Technology").get_url() + ' ';
                technologyTask += oListItem.get_item("Technology").get_description() + ' ';
            };

            //put items into loopable arrays
            var LinkTitleArray = LinkTitle.split(' ');
            var ActiveArray = active.split(' ');
            var accountingLinkArray = accountingLink.split(' ');
            var accountingTaskArray = accountingTask.split(' ');
            var hrLinkArray = hrList.split(' ');
            var hrTaskArray = hrTask.split(' ');
            var technologyLinkArray = technologyLink.split(' ');
            var technologyTaskArray = technologyTask.split(' ');

            var deptList = document.getElementById("deptList");
            var taskList = document.getElementById('taskList');
            var deptChoice = deptList.options[deptList.selectedIndex].text;

            var taskText = '';
            var taskLink = '';

            for(var i = 0; i<ActiveArray.length-1; i++){  //modify the two drop downs
                if(deptChoice == "accounting"){
                    taskText = accountingTaskArray[i];
                    taskLink = accountingLinkArray[i];
                }
                else if(deptChoice == "hr"){
                    taskText = hrTaskArray[i];
                    taskLink = hrLinkArray[i];
                }
                else if(deptChoice = "technology"){
                    taskText = technologyTaskArray[i];
                    taskLink = technologyLinkArray[i];
                }
                console.log(taskText + "//" + taskLink);
                var newOption = document.createElement("option"); //create new link
                newOption.value = taskLink; //add link in the value field
                newOption.innerHTML = taskText; //add text of the new option
                taskList.appendChild(newOption); //add new option to dropdown
            }
        }

        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }

        function JumpToUrl(url){
            location.href = url;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="LinkDisplay">
        <h1> What do you want to do? </h1>

        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>   </th>
                <th>Task</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><select name= "deptList" id="deptList"  onchange="javascript:retrieveListItems(deptList.options[deptList.selectedIndex].text)">
                    <option>accounting</option>
                    <option>hr</option>
                    <option>technology</option>
                </select></td>

                <td>   </td>

                <td><select name="taskList" id="taskList" onchange="javascript:JumpToUrl(taskList.options[taskList.selectedIndex].value)">
                        <option></option>
                        <option></option>
                        <option></option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

In the *onQuerySucceeded* function, I try to get the url/description from the hyperlink fields in the List. The issue with this is that not all of the departments will have the same number of links, so I shouldn't be pulling all of the fields in. However, I am not sure the best workaround. Maybe add an extra parameter to *onQuerySucceeded* so that I can pass the selected department using the onChange function. I pass the necessary value to retrieveListItems, just not all the way through the succeeded function. Workarounds anyone?

Comment: If you are trying to implement cascading drop-downs, I would highly recommend looking at the third-party jQuery library [SPServices](https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation).  It has an implementation of cascading drop-downs that uses backing lists as configuration, but in a slightly different way to how you are doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You don't need a workaround, you need basic JavaScript**

As you said:

> Maybe add an extra parameter to onQuerySucceeded so that I can pass the selected department using the onChange function. I pass the necessary value to retrieveListItems, just not all the way through the succeeded function

**This is an example of Async code passing data to the succeed function:**

Test it as a Chrome Snippet:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/snippets/?hl=en

```
function getItems(listName,siteUrl){
    var request={};
    request.listName=listName;
    request.siteUrl=siteUrl || _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(request.siteUrl);
    var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(request.listName);
    request.query=SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
    request.itemCollection=list.getItems(request.query);
    ctx.load(request.itemCollection);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(  processItems.bind(request)  ,failure);
}
function processItems() {
    var received=this;//received 'request' from Caller
    received.items=[];
    var listEnumerator = received.itemCollection.getEnumerator();
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var listitem = listEnumerator.get_current();
        received.items.push(listitem.get_id());
    }
    console.info(received.listName,'has',received.items.length,'items IDs:',received.items);
}
function failure(sender, args){
    console.error(args.get_message());
}
console.clear();
for(var cycle=1;cycle<4;cycle++){// call multiple times to show ASYNC result in the console
    console.log('Calling 3 lists a couple of times.. cycle:',cycle);
    getItems('Tasks');
    getItems('Documents');
    getItems('Images');
}
```

`.bind()` has been standard JavaScript for a very long time, ofcourse Microsoft got late into the game and had its own (oldskool) `Function.CreateDelegate` implementation, since IE9 they comply with the standard
See: [Differing ways to make executeQueryAsync calls - Function.createDelegate (is old IE8 code)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164893/differing-ways-to-make-calls-delegate/164898#164898)

You can bind anything you want, and Objects are passed by Reference, not by value, so you could built a whole datastructure in your main thread

> iJS:Passing data from an async function to a processing function with .bind

Answer (score 0):

Is using InfoPath an option for you? Rules can be set up to show / hide fields and sections when you select specific choices.

Example I found online: https://manojssharepointblog.wordpress.com/2012/12/23/infopath-2013-web-browser-creating-cascading-dropdown-fields-with-no-code/