# How can I know REST API request done?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I use in my application a request REST API which works asynchronous.
How I can do to know the request is done?

Comment: You can set alert or flag kind of logic for that. You can stop async behavior of REST using `async:false,`

Comment: Theres success and fail method. Also if you want to do something after a call is complete, call that method from success or Complete method of Ajax call.

Comment: If an answer was helpful could you remove your question from the SO unanswered list, by marking it as answered, tnx

Answer (score 5):

Ajax/REST calls **do** let know when they succeed or fail, that is the whole point.
And you do **not** need to convert code to *synchronous* calls.

In the old days you would use **Callback functions**, nowadays you use **Promises**
(*you can even mix these, Callbacks are executed first*)

The **best post** explaining all this async stuff is:
(*it has 2757 upvotes, you can +1*)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

#### Code

*because Link-only posts are not encouraged and the admins are watching me*

*orginally from a jQuery answer*

Here is code with both Callback functions and Methods chained to the $.ajax Promise
*learn to [use Chrome Snippets](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/snippets/?hl=en) to run SP code without going through a long & complex built proces*

```
    console.clear();
    var site=_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    var listName='Documents';
    $.ajax({
        url: site + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')",
        method: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        async: true, // is the default value, so you can leave it out
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success:function(data){//this is a Callback function
            console.log('success Callback', data)
        },
        error:function(data){//this is a Callback function
            console.log('error Callback', data)
        }
    }).done(function(data){//this is a method on the Promise chain
        console.log('success ',data);
    }).fail(function(data){//this is a method on the Promise chain
        console.error('error ',data);
    }).always(function(data){//this is a method on the Promise chain
        console.log('always ',data);
    });
```

So the **.done method** is interchangable with the **success Callback**

Note that they are both executed in this example.. Callbacks first.

(modern) Promises are more powerful, (oldschool) Callbacks are used in most blogposts.

*I had to RTFM as well*

`.success` and `.error` **methods** you see in blogposts are deprecated since jQuery 1.8 (use `.done` and `.fail`) but do still work

#### Yes you can do ajax without jQuery

You do not need that 90KB library,  it is just a fancy wrapper around native JavaScript code:

```
var site=_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,
    listName='Documents',
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.open("GET",site+"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+listName+"')", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json;odata=nometadata");
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-RequestDigest",document.getElementById('__REQUESTDIGEST').value);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function (data) {
  if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;//no response received yet 
  if (xhr.status===200) console.info('success');
  console.info('I got:',listName,data);
};
xhr.send();
```

A modern replacement for `XMLHttpRequest` is `fetch`, but it does have some drawbacks: https://davidwalsh.name/fetch
You do need a polyfill becuase only Microsoft Edge 14 now supports it.

Promises are native JavaScript as well but also require a polyfill, Edge is fine but IE still stinks.
Note that jQuery does `done` and `fail`, native JS is `then` and `catch`

When diving deeper into REST, be sure to understand the different odata responses: https://blogs.office.com/2014/08/13/json-light-support-rest-sharepoint-api-released/

Microsoft is pushing an open-source team to write a wrapper around SP-REST functionality. https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-JS-Core
(Remember: this does require Promise & Fetch polyfills to run)

#### Stackoverflow related posts:

- [Differing ways to make executeQueryAsync calls - Function.createDelegate (is old IE8 code)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164893/differing-ways-to-make-executequeryasync-calls-function-createdelegate)
  Explains how to pass data to a succeed function, and why `createDelegate` is pointless nowadays

iJS iREST

Comment: This answers only the case when you use JavaScript...

Comment: Correct. But you have not been around for nearly 2 years, Wictor (http://i.imgur.com/TOr2bHk.jpg) If someone asks a REST question here on SO, and they tag it 'online' I will go *all-in* with my SO-points  it is a JavaScript question. (btw. +1 for spelling JavaScript correct 

Comment: LOL. Nuff said.

Comment: It wouldn't be a bad idea, some more gamification/poker with SO credits. Current system sucks.

Comment: Love that you saved old pictures of my SO points!

Answer (score 0):

There's no acknowledgement of asynchronous requests, it's kind of the point. If you want to know if the request succeeds or fails you either have to change your code to synchronous operations OR use asynchronous methods in your code to wait for the response (exactly how, depends on where your code is executing; JavaScript, C# etc).