# Implementing paging after getting data using REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I am using below code to get data from a list later binding to a table but while implementing paging, I am facing some issues.

```
function GetData(arrayID)
{

$.each(arrayID, function( index, value ) {
if(arrayID[index]!=null)
{
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('test')/items?$select=Array_ID,Title,LAST_NAME,EMPLOYEE_CODE,DESIGNATION,LOCATION&$filter=Array_ID eq '"+arrayID[index]+"'";
$.ajax({  
    url: url,  
    method: "GET",  
    headers: {  
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"  
    },  
    complete:function(data){   
    },
    success: function(data) {  
    var arrayID = data.d.results[0].ORACLE_HR_ID;
    var employeeName = data.d.results[0].Title + " " + data.d.results[0].LAST_NAME;
    ShowData(ohrID,employeeName);
    },  
    error: function(data) {  
        console.log("error");  
    }  
});  
}
});

$('#tblCustomListData').dataTable({
        paging: true,
        searching: true,
        bDestroy: true,
        "iDisplayLength": 5 ,
        "lengthMenu": [5,10, 25, 50, 100]
    });

});
}
```

This is not working perfectly as the code of paging needs to be executed after the completion of .each function. So can I make the paging code to be executed at the end of  this .each function?

Answer (score 4):

Define your

`$.ajax({`

as

```
var call = $.ajax({
// ...
});
```

Then you can wait until the `call` is `done` before you start to populate your `dataTable`:

```
call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
    $('#tblCustomListData').dataTable({
    // ...
    });
});
```

There are a few resources for using DataTables with SP, and I'd give a recommendation to have a look [at this](http://info.summit7systems.com/blog/who-needs-a-data-view-web-part-sharepoint-rest-and-datatables-net) as the first task.

Comment: i have tried call.done but this is also firing before the completion of the ajax call

Answer (score 1):

You can't do async ajax inside a loop

You want to wait for each ajax call to be resolved

See an old post: [How can I know REST API request done?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/192946/how-can-i-know-rest-api-request-done)

for my long answer

---

Related answer:

- [REST API call in SharePoint gets result, but when returns result becomes undefined](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/215456/rest-api-call-in-sharepoint-gets-result-but-when-returns-result-becomes-undefin/215461#215461)

Comment: So is there anything that I can do for code to run after ajax call inside loop

Comment: set ``async:false`` but don't get agree with me when you code takes loads of seconds to finish.. better to learn to deal with promises as described in the other posts.

Comment: even async false is not working to make paging work properly, I know the issue is that I need to execute paging code to run at the end. So still trying for it.

Comment: You have to learn to work with (multiple) Promises; for jQuery see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878887/how-do-you-work-with-an-array-of-jquery-deferreds (the first relevant I found)