# get modified by (editor) when getting list items using CSOM/JSOM through JavaScript

Tags: 2010, javascript, csom, jsom, editor

I am able to get items from a list using CSOM/JSOM using JavaScript and it seems to pull in the `Created By` (`Author`) value but it does not seem to pull the `Modified By` (`Editor`) value.

How can I get the `Modified By` (`Editor`) value also?

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function()
{
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current()
    var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("test");
    var view = list.get_views().getByTitle("All Items");
    context.load(view);

    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function(sender, args)
    {
        var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
        query.set_viewXml("<View><Query>" + view.get_viewQuery() + "</Query></View>");

        var items = list.getItems(query);

        context.load(items);

        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function(sender, args)
        {
            var listEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
            while(listEnumerator.moveNext())
            {
                var listItem = listEnumerator.get_current();

                // this works
                var createdBy = listItem.get_item("Author");

                // THIS DOES NOT WORK
                // THIS DOES NOT WORK
                // THIS DOES NOT WORK
                // THIS DOES NOT WORK
                // THIS DOES NOT WORK
                var createdBy = listItem.get_item("Editor");
            }
        }), Function.createDelegate(this, function(){}));
    }), Function.createDelegate(this, function(){}));
}, "sp.js");
```

Comment: May be because you have created 'createdBy' variable two times ?

Comment: Note that ``createDelegate`` bloats your code and is old IE8 code: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164893/differing-ways-to-make-executequeryasync-calls-function-createdelegate/164898#164898

Comment: @RonakPatel: Naw, it should just replace the variable.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Ah. Thanks! Does it matter that at my company all SP sites default to IE8 mode even though we're on IE 11?

Comment: Yes, bind is available since IE9 and officially Microsoft does not support anything below IE9 anymore since january 12th of this year.. so if you put in a support call they will say.. "We don't support IE8"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out there is nothing wrong with my code but rather my list has too many fields and `getItems` isn't returning all of them. When I deleted one field from the list everything worked as expected.

I am not sure how to get all fields even for lists with a lot of fields but for this particular issue deleting one field did fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the field `"Editor"`. Try below code:

```
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function()
{
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current()
    var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("test");
    var view = list.get_views().getByTitle("All Items");
    context.load(view);

    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function(sender, args)
    {
        var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
        query.set_viewXml("<View><Query>" + view.get_viewQuery() + "</Query></View>");

        var items = list.getItems(query);

        context.load(items,'Include(Editor)');

        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function(sender, args)
        {
            var listEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
            while(listEnumerator.moveNext())
            {
                var listItem = listEnumerator.get_current();

                // this works
                var createdBy = listItem.get_item("Author");

                var modifiedBy = listItem.get_item("Editor");
            }
        }), Function.createDelegate(this, function(){}));
    }), Function.createDelegate(this, function(){}));
}, "sp.js");
```

Comment: Thank you. It turns out there is nothing wrong with my code but rather my list has too many fields and `getItems` isn't returning all of them. When I deleted one field from the list everything worked as expected. Odd.

Answer (score 0):

It should work can you try below code,

```
<script language="ecmascript" type="text/ecmascript">

        var listItem;
        var list;
        var clientContext;

        function getFieldUserValue() {

            this.clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            if (this.clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {
                var webSite = clientContext.get_web();
                this.list = webSite.get_lists().getByTitle("CustomList");
                this.listItem = list.getItemById(1);
                clientContext.load(this.listItem);
                this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadFailed));
            }
        }

        function OnLoadSuccess(sender, args) {
            var fieldUserValueCreatedBy = this.listItem.get_item("Author");
            var fieldUserValueModifiedBy = this.listItem.get_item("Editor");
            alert("Created By: " + fieldUserValueModifiedBy.get_lookupValue() + "\n Modified By: " + fieldUserValueModifiedBy.get_lookupValue() + "\n");
        }


        function OnLoadFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. It turns out there is nothing wrong with my code but rather my list has too many fields and `getItems` isn't returning all of them. When I deleted one field from the list everything worked as expected. Odd.