# find out what item id failed executeQueryAsync item creation

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, csom

How can i find what item failed executeQueryAsync add item method ?

this is my code :

```
var itemArray = [];
var siteUrl = "http://MySite/MM/cm";
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('xy');

var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
oListItem.set_item('FullName', "ali");
oListItem.set_item('CellPhone', "555-666");

oListItem.update();
itemArray[i] = oListItem;
clientContext.load(itemArray[i]);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    console.log("item created in : ", oListItem.get_id());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

I con not find out what item is duplicate in item creation that my query is failed ! if i can find it then i can update it and continue with others !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the item you wanted to  create, to the failed function with standard JavaScript `bind`
(*supported in* InternetExplorer *since* IE9)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

```
...

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed.bind(oListItem) );

...

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    var oListItem = this;
    console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Explained in detail in:

- [Differing ways to make executeQueryAsync calls - Function.createDelegate (is old IE8 code)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164893/differing-ways-to-make-executequeryasync-calls-function-createdelegate)
- [Looping jsom getItems](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/201652/looping-jsom-getitems/201669#201669)