# Include callback functions directly in executeQueryAsync without delegates

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, jsom

I am tryting to create module pattern with ExecuteQueryAsync like this:

```
    UsersMngt = (function () {

        getUserIdByEmail = function(email){

        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = clientContext.get_web();

        var user = web.get_siteUsers().getByEmail(email);


        clientContext.load(user);

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));


        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(alert('yes'),alert('no'));               
}; //getUserIdByEmail




return{
    GetUserIdByEmail:getUserIdByEmail,
};
```

})();

and then I want to call it like:

```
UsersMngt.GetUserIdByEmail('user.name@email.com')
```

but, everytime I call it, with or without success, it always gives me both "yes" and "no" (success and failure). It also retrieves data I need in case of succces.

How can I include functions directly in "executeQueryAsync" without creating actually delegates somewhere else? I would like everything to be kept within the same code structure.

So far, it only works with delegates.

Thank you for ideas and help

Comment: If an answer was helpful could you remove your question from the SO unanswered list, by marking it as answered, tnx

Comment: Thanks, will do. I wanted to do it originally but due to rules of this site I had to wait two days and then it slipped my mind:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you, I solved it like this, because I wanted to use annonymous functions:

```
UsersMngt = (function () {

getUserIdByEmail = function(email){

        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = clientContext.get_web();

        var user = web.get_siteUsers().getByEmail(email);


        clientContext.load(user);


        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            function (){
                    alert("yes")
            },
            function(){
                    alert("no")
            }            
        )}; //getUserIdByEmail


return{
    GetUserIdByEmail:getUserIdByEmail,
};
```

})();

Comment: Good, and since the declaration (*they might be ananymous, but still exist*) is **inside** the ``getUserIdByEmail`` function **scope**, they have access to all variables from that scope. That eleviates the need for oldSkool Function.createDelegate or modern ``.bind()`` But be carefull!! it is async code so your error/success function will execute at a point in time where variables *Could* have changed. Non-anonymous but referenced Functions are saver to use, as you can never access the calling functions scope (unless you use bind() to make a **copy** of a Scope) so less prone to logic errors

Comment: Hi Danny, thank you. I used Deffered object in this function in the end so I can check for success or fail and it works like a charm! :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

This code executes **asynchronous**

code does not stop when executed, the Success or Error **Callback Functions** execute when the Async operation is done.

It is like telling someone else to get you a coffee

What you now program

```
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(alert('yes'),alert('no'));
```

Is: you send someone to get a coffee, and before he leaves he says "Yes"

The parameters you have to supply are Function **Definitions** *so without the **( )***,
not Function **Calls** you do now

That whole `Function.createDelegate` is old Microsoft IE8 stuff,
ditch and learn modern IE9 notation: [Differing ways to make executeQueryAsync calls - Function.createDelegate (is old IE8 code)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164893/differing-ways-to-make-executequeryasync-calls-function-createdelegate-is-old/164898#164898)

More details: [Looping jsom getItems](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/201652/looping-jsom-getitems/201669#201669)

Answer (score 0):

Once this `clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));` query is executed, it will call the **onQuerySucceeded** or **onQueryFailed** functions depending on the result of the query.

I advice you to call the **executeQueryAsync** just one. and write alert messages inside **onQuerySucceeded** or **onQueryFailed** functions.

Also createDelegate is too old now.
Using just this would be fine:

```
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded,onQueryFailed);
```

Comment: For simplicity **one** executeQueryAsync is helpful; but you can execute more: *You, get me a Coffee!, You! get me a bagel You! get me the newspaper* Three asynchronous commands... maybe like: *Update Item, Update ParentItem, Trigger workflow*  Do read how to pass variables to a function