# AJAX Pass variable to successhandler

Tags: rest, jquery, ajax

Considering this sample code, how can it be changed so that it makes the 'something' variable available in the succeshandler function?

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/web/lists";

function addList()
{
    var something = "ABC";
    getData(url).success(successHandler);
}

function successHandler(data)
{
    console.log(something);
    console.log(data);
}


function getData(url)
{

    return $.ajax({
        url:url,
        method:"GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    });
}
```

**Update**
The topic was marked off topic for not being directly Sharepoint related which I guess is fair, however I've had essentially this same problem for a couple of Sharepoint problems so tried to write it down as generic as possible. Here's the real scenario:

A list of **events**

A list of **registrations** containing a lookup to the event.

I want to make a table of *all* events, including those with zero subscriptions, with event details plus the number of registrations made.

Using Rob's answer it will pass a static variable, but as explained above it needs iterate through a list that was queried before. (get # of registrations for each event). Using the .bind method I am able to pass on the registration data to the next function, which is awesome!

```
$(function(){   

    var events = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Events')";
    var registrations = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Registrations')";    
    var eventsList = [];    

    getData(events + "/items").success(function(data){dataHandler(data);});

    function dataHandler(data)
    {
        for(i = 0; i< data.d.results.length; i++)
        {
            var eventData =  data.d.results[i];
            var key = eventData.Id;
            // Check if this event has already been added to the overview               
            if($.inArray(key, eventsList) == -1)
            {
                //if not get its number of registrations and add it to the overview
                getData(registrations + "/items?$filter=Event/Id eq " + key).success(addEvent.bind(eventData));         
                eventsList.push(key);               
            }           
        }   
    }

    function addEvent(registrationData, eventData)
    {
        var r = registrationData.d.results.length; // number of registrations
        var eventData = this;

        var row = "<tr><td>"+eventData.Title+"</td><td>"+r+"</td></tr>"; // construct the row containing data from both sources         
        $('#overview tr:last').after(row);      
    }

    function getData(url)
    {       
        return $.ajax({
            url:url,
            method:"GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
function addList()
{
    var something = "ABC";
    getData(url).success(function(data) { 
        successHandler(data, something); 
    });
}

function successHandler(data, something)
{
    console.log(something);
    console.log(data);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Robs answer works,
But you might as well move the whole function inside the addList **`scope`**
(*unless the function is called from other functions as well*)

The JavaScript `.bind()` method  is the JS way of passing scope

```
function addList() {
    var something = "ABC";
    getData(url).success( 
       successHandler.bind(something) //bind the function with a different scope
    );
}

function successHandler(data) {
    var something = this ; // this is the scope
    console.log(something);
    console.log(data);
}
```

For more explanation and usage see:

- https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=ibind

In the old IE8 days SharePoint needed its own `Function.CreateDelegate` method:

and you see that  in many blogs and code snippets

- [Differing ways to make executeQueryAsync calls - Function.createDelegate (is old IE8 code)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164893/differing-ways-to-make-executequeryasync-calls-function-createdelegate-is-old/164898#164898)

**`.bind()` is standard JavaScript since IE9**