# executeQueryAsync does not run success or failure statements

Tags: 2013, javascript

Whenever I call `executeQuereyAsync` after an `update()`, it does not run either the success or failure methods. Elsewhere in my code, I call it after `load()` and it works fine.

So this works fine in my code, alerting "this worked!":

```
clientContext.load(oListItem, "holderListID");  
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    function(sender, args) {    // if query succeeds...
        alert('this worked!');
        }
    },
    function(sender, args) {    // if query fails...
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' +     args.get_stackTrace());
    }
);
```

While this correctly updates `oListItem` but does not alert anything, skipping past to the next line of code:

```
function updateThings() {
    //run set_items() on things
    oListItem.update();
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync( Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
                                     Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    alert('It works!');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

I am creating a simple checkout/return system. Here is my code for checking an item out, which includes my current workaround for not being able to access the success callback. As it is written, this code works, but the success/failure functions after `update()` are never called:

```
function clickCheckout(){
    state = 0;
    checkout = 1;

    try{
        getId();
        isCheckedOut();
    }
    catch(err) {
        alert("Please try again, checkout failed");
    }
}

function getId() {
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();                 

    oListItem = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Equipment Checkout').getItemById(listItemID);                           
}

function isCheckedOut() {
    clientContext.load(oListItem, holderListID);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        function(sender, args) {    // if query succeeds...
            oldUsername = oListItem.get_item(holderListID).get_lookupValue();
            if(oldUsername != 'Not in use') { 
                if(checkout == 1) { 
                    alert("Cannot check out: item is currently checked out by " + oldUsername);
                } else {
                    returnItem();
                }
            } else { 
                if(checkout == 0) {
                    alert("Item was not checked out!");
                } else {    
                    checkoutItem();
                }
            }
        },
        function(sender, args) {    // if query fails...
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
    );
}

function checkoutItem() {    
    var today = new Date();
    oListItem.set_item(dateTimeID, today);

    var user = new SP.FieldUserValue(); 

    user.set_lookupId(_spPageContextInfo.userId);   
    oListItem.set_item(holderListID, user);     

    oListItem.update();
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync( Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
                                     Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    setTimeout(setMoreInfo,300);    // workaround to allow executeQueryAsync() to finish
}

function setMoreInfo() {    // continuing from the workaround
    clientContext.load(oListItem, holderListID);    
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        function(sender, args) {    // if query succeeds...
            newUsername = oListItem.get_item(holderListID).get_lookupValue();   
            oListItem.set_item(holderUsernameListID, newUsername);              
            oListItem.update();
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync( Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
                                             Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));    
            alert("Item is successfully checked out!");
            redirectToView();   // sends user to another page
        }, 
        function(sender, args) {    // if query fails...
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
    );
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    alert('It works!');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: can you post full code ... any be some error within the upper part of code.

Comment: [Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245356.aspx#Anchor_2) from MSDN shows calling `.load()` after making an update.  It might be required.  Though, I see a lot of examples doing updates without the `.load()`, and I imagine they can't all be wrong either.

Comment: @MonicaJagani I just added most of my code.

Comment: @wjervis I just tried that, and nothing changed :/

Comment: Clean up your code and ditch that IE8 syntax, see [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164893/differing-ways-to-make-executequeryasync-calls-function-createdelegate-is-old), then ditch all that ``alert`` use and learn to use ``console.log(x)`` to the F12 console. Only then (when you code is better readable) can you do some serious debugging of your coding error. At first glance you are going wrong with the scope of ``clientContext``

Comment: The alerts are actually for the user, so they can know what is going on when interacting with the page

Comment: Yeah I personally wouldn't use `clientContext` and the `oListItem` as global variables, which may be your problem.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions guys! After changing the old syntax as @Danny'365CSI'Engelman suggested, it seems to be working. I think the scope I had for clientContext was messing things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After cleaning up my code as per the suggestions of the comments above and the info in the answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164893/differing-ways-to-make-executequeryasync-calls-function-createdelegate-is-old), it seems to be working.

I removed the apparently outdated `Function.createDelegate`

and simply using

```
oListItem.update();
clientContext.executeQueryAsync( onQuerySucceeded, 
                                 onQueryFailed);
```

or putting the functions directly as the callbacks works for me now. It seems using `this` was having issues because of the scope of my `clientContext`

Answer (score 0):

if you call the `this.onQuerySucceeded`, that function has to be outside of the function you are calling `executeQueryAsync()`. So your last example is a matter of breaking the `onQuerySucceeded` and `onQueryFailed` outside of the function calling the execute.

If you are creating a list item, you need to load the item variable in the clientContext first using `clientContext.load(oListItem);`

Comment: I just added more complete code; the success/fail functions are outside of the function calling executeQueryAsync. I am only modifying list items, not creating new ones, but thanks!

Comment: That '*has to be outside*' depends on what the ``this`` scope is. In most code examples that is the ``window`` object, then yes, 'outside' is the global scope.