# rest api to insert value in title field of list

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I want to insert "100" value in my sharepoint list title field. I tried jsom but it not even giving alert. Below is the code. What change I need to make in `JSOM` code or can someone help with rest api.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var siteUrl = 'url';   

jQuery(document).ready(function ()
{
alert('23');
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', createListItem);
}); 


function createListItem() {   
  alert('1');
var firstName = "100";   

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);   
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Emp');   
var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();   
this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);   

oListItem.set_item('FirstName', firstName);   

oListItem.update();   
clientContext.load(oListItem);   
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));   
}   

function onQuerySucceeded() {   

alert('Item created Successfully !!!!');   

}   

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {   

       alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());   
    }   

</script>
```

Comment: Which alert are you not getting? The one in createListItem function? also try writing document.ready below all functions.

Comment: any alert alert('23');

Comment: for your ``createDelegate`` usage see: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164893/differing-ways-to-make-executequeryasync-calls-function-createdelegate-is-old

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing the `jQuery(document).ready` function below all functions in the script tag.

The REST API solution would be a simple function below

```
function addNewItem(url, data) {
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

Where URL is `var addNewItemUrl = "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Emp')/Items";`
and data as below

```
var data = {
    __metadata: { 'type': 'SP.Data.EmpListItem' },
    FirstName: 'Some Name'
};
```

Comment: can you please help me with edit you rest script full and paste here. I am new to it so could not understand which one to put first